# How to disable yandex in tomcat?

Tags: security, hosts.deny

Yandex.ru spiders are known of disobeying robots.txt. In Apache, you can disable yandex in htaccess file. How can I do the same thing with Tomcat?
I'm using ubuntu server, so I thoght about appropriate entries in hosts.deny, but I'm not sure if

```
ALL: yandex.ru
```

will be sufficient and efficient, cause bot's are often named like spider31.yandex.ru.
Could you show example of blocking this bots via hosts.deny (or any other way)?

Answer (score 1):

You want to put this in hosts.deny:

```
ALL: .yandex.ru
```

Notice the . which means any subdomain of.